# Ruby ajax call initiates unwated Popup Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have an `AJAX` call for one of my routes in my `Ruby on Rails` project. It calls a method in a `Ruby Controller` to update flags on several of my objects, and then I need the page to reload to reflect those changes. This was my solution, at the end of the `Ruby` method:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render js: "window.location = '#{processed_items_path(params)}'" }
end
```

This does exactly what I need it to do, it refreshes the page and pulls the user back to the top to see a flash notice. However, before doing so, it pops up a window that says:

```
The page at localhost says:
  "window.location = '#{processed_items_path(params)}'"
```

And it requires you to click `"OK"` before you can continue on. Is there any way to get rid of that box?

Comment: if you want to redirect your page then why are you using ajax?

Comment: Because I'm trying to get information from a series of checkboxes on a view that aren't in form. The boxes are part of a dynamically generated table. So I use a javascript method to grab the information I need and an ajax call to send it back to the controller.

Comment: ok so you are getting all the information by your ajax call then why would you want to redirect your page after that?

Comment: I'm sending a list of IDs to my controller. Then I find those items and edit them. After I'm finished editing, I need the page to refresh so the table reflects the new information.

Comment: Instead of redirecting, you can render your partial containing table and since you are rendering it after you have edited your resource so it'll automatically contain new information

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments above, instead of *redirecting* it'll be better to just **render your partial containing your table**

I'm assuming your ajax call is working (*as it's taking you to your method*). For rendering your partial you can do:

```
def your_method
  #your logic of updating attributes
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {} # this will let rails look for a file named your_method.js.erb in your view
  end
end
```

Now you simply need to render your partial in **your_method.js.erb**

```
$("#some_id_of_parent_element").html("<%=j render partial: "partial_containing_table", locals: { :your_local => partial_local} %>");
```

For details refer to [**`Working with javascript in rails`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example)

Comment: Now instead of a dialog box with the refresh code, it's a dialog box with what looks like the html of the entire table that you have to "OK".

Comment: It seems like it doesn't matter what lines of code I actually use, if I do anything with javascript after that ajax call it pops up a dialog box the user has to "OK." I just wanted to know how to make that stop.

Comment: @user3254621 what you mean by **it's a dialog box with what looks like the html of the entire table?**

Comment: @user3254621 if everything is setup correctly then dialog box won't appear. which browser are you using and can you post your controller code with your ajax call method?